# Lookup filters on same level of object

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, administration

I had CustomObjectA and Account standard object. 'CustomObjectB' is a junction object between CustomObjectA and Account object. Now, on Case object I had Account lookup filed. When I click on Account lookup field on Case object needs to search based on CustomObjectA fields also.

Please suggest the solutions.

**Note:** By default we can search using Account object fields, but I want search using both CustomObjectA and Account object fields.

Comment: hmm looks like you need custom lookup feature. https://gist.github.com/jeffdonthemic/4f2feb55a16b95a37798

Comment: You can't search on CustomObjectA with a standard functionality because each account may have many junction objects and many CustomObjectsA linked with it. You can search on parent object fields (because there can be no more than 1 parent so we know which record to search) but not on child objects because there can be more than 1 child.

Comment: @Ratan , Oles Malkov: Thank You! for share your suggestions. Custom lookup is really helpful, using this we can add our own filters in search. Still I am looking for any out of box functionality or any other easy solutions we can achieve.